# Displaying an image coming from database through web service in Collection View

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, storyboard, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS and trying to write my apps as pure iOS 5 app using the new storyboard feature.

I want to calling services and displays all images that coming on Collection View.

So, I need to save Image, URL, Number of Like, Number of comment and Comments.

Would you pelase help me in this ?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    MyImageCollection *myCollection = (MyImageCollection *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        myCollection.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[natureImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *arrayListg = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First Image URL",@"Second Image URL",@"Third Image URL",@"Forth Image URL", nil];

        NSURL* url;
        NSURLRequest* request;

        for(int i = 0; i <4 ; i++)
        {

            url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayListg objectAtIndex:i]];
            request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                                       NSData * data,
                                                       NSError * error) {
                                       if (!error){
                                           UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                           myCollection.myImageView.image = image;
                                       }

                                   }
             ];
        }


        myCollection.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[animalsImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    }

    return myCollection;
}
```

Comment: You can't use UICollectionView on iOS 5. What have you tried?

Comment: so how i can do it? would you please help me ?

Comment: You will not get help from Stack Overflow without trying yourself. See here... http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ Especially on such a common issue it is obvious that you have done nothing and expect everyone here to spoon feed you the code.

Comment: Sorry for that, but i have tried to do this, and I encountered some problems, you can see my updating code on the main comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use UICollectionView on IOS 5 and less then IOS 6.0 then you find this error

error : 'Could not instantiate class named UICollectionView' and your app will crash...

So, if your requirement is on IOS 5 then please use PSTCollectinView

[PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView)